# How to create reactive output from other reactive output in R Shiny App?

Tags: r, shiny

[Picture of Shiny App output. Table I want data from is on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4jFe.png)

**How to store and reuse reactive data to make multiple outputs in Shiny?**

I want to create another output that displays information like the most profitable trial or percentages of times the player got BJ from this simulation. The code uses the inputs to run my simulateBlackjack function which is random. I am thinking that I need to store the results of the simulateBlackjack() so that I can harness the data, how can I do this?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Blackjack 'Perfect Strategy' Simulation"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            numericInput("wager", "How much to wager per hand?", 5,
                         1, 1000), 
            sliderInput("hands",
                        "Number of hands to play:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 1000,
                        value = 50),
            
            sliderInput("decks",
                        "Number of decks:",
                        min = 4,
                        max = 8,
                        value = 8),
            img(src = "https://wizardofodds.com/blackjack/images/bj_4d_h17.gif", width = 225, height = 600)
            
            
        ),
        

        mainPanel(
          dataTableOutput(outputId = "simResults"),
          verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "analysis")
          
        )
    )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

    reactData <- reactive({simulateBlackjack(input$wager,input$hands,input$decks)})
    #data <- reactData()
    
    output$simResults <- DT::renderDataTable({
        datatable(reactData(), rownames = TRUE, options = list(pageLength = 13, lengthChange = FALSE))
    })
    
    # output$analysis <- renderPrint(max(data[13,])) 
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This is not a reprex, please create a function that at least gives a result insted of the black-jack one

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(shiny)   

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Blackjack 'Perfect Strategy' Simulation"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("wager", "How much to wager per hand?", 5,
                   1, 1000), 
      sliderInput("hands",
                  "Number of hands to play:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 1000,
                  value = 50),
      
      sliderInput("decks",
                  "Number of decks:",
                  min = 4,
                  max = 8,
                  value = 8),
      img(src = "https://wizardofodds.com/blackjack/images/bj_4d_h17.gif", width = 225, height = 600)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput(outputId = "simResults"),
      verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "analysis")
      
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  reactData <- reactive({
    req(input$wager,input$hands,input$decks)
    simulateBlackjack(input$wager,input$hands,input$decks)
  })
  
  output$simResults <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(reactData(), rownames = TRUE, options = list(pageLength = 13, lengthChange = FALSE))
  })
  
  output$analysis <- renderPrint(
    max(reactData()[13,])
  ) 
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```